# Copy only the first 2 characters from a formfield to other field dynamically

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form field with the last name and want to generate a customer ID starting with the first two characters from their last name in caps and add a random number to it. So I need the other field which dynamically updates with only the first two characters in uppercase. This is what I have so far:

**HTML**:

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
  <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="" onKeyUp="document.getElementById('textfield2').value=this.value">
  <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
document.getElementById('textfield2').setAttribute('maxlength',2)
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('textfield2').value=this.value.substr(0,2).toUppercase()`

Comment: Why are you using `maxlength`? What do you think that will do?

Comment: I think the maxlength is to stop the user altering it beyond 2 chars. I'd just disable the input altogether to stop them changing it at all. especially if the changes can get wiped when the first field is changed. If not just add the maxlength attribute to the html...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two first characters  from your input and put them in the second with javascript :

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
  <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="" onKeyUp="document.getElementById('textfield2').value=this.value.subst‌​r(0,2).toUppercase()">
  <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="">
</form>
```

I am not sure but I think that the javascript code don't care about the attribut "maxlength". Futhermore, you need use `toUpperCase` in order to have your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
    <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="" onKeyUp="txt(this.value)">
    <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="">
</form>
<script>
    function txt(value) {
        document.getElementById('textfield2').value = value.substr(0,2).toUpperCase();
    }
</script>
```

hope it works